# R dataframe column to character array

Tags: r

I am newbee to R.

Trying to play with this language a bit. All I am trying is

1) I have a dataframe "df", which has one column "desc" which is String 
2) I did a load csv to create the dataframe

Issue:

1) when I am doing    w <- df$desc
it is returning a object but I am unable to figure the object. I tried is.vector, is.charaecter(w) nothing returns "true". I was going thru a book and it mentioned it should be a vector.

2) I have to create a character array to do further processing can anyone please help me how to do the processing or conversion

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Please supply data for use to work with.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use `str` to find out what kind of object you have. It's probably a factor. What dimensions do you need in the array? You really should study some introductions and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the class of an object, use this:

```
class(w)
```

or, if you want to know the classes of all the columns in a data.frame (called "X" in this example), try this:

```
sapply(X, class)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments... It is really great to see the quick response... That helped !!